# How to detect browser plug-ins?

Tags: javascript, plugins, browser

Is there any specific way through scripting or Java to find which plug-ins are installed on the browser?

Answer (score 3):

in javascript

you can put navigator.plugins

this will give you an array of plugins . which consists of plugin name,filename, version,length,description etc...

Answer (score 1):

As @Val said, the navigator.plugins object is the first place to look. If you need fine grained version information, you may also need [Pinlady.net's PluginDection](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/) for older browsers which lack the version property or which completely lack navigator.plugins object (such as IE before IE 9).

Answer (score 0):

Client side:

Create an object (to be run by a browser plugin) that passes a value to javascript on the web page. If the javascript code hasn't received anything, your browser didn't execute the object, so there's probably no plugin, or it's turned off.

Server side:

do the same, but make your object request something from the server. If no such request comes around, there's no plugin.